# Trying to create a network file for Gephi but my code gives this error - "cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object"

Tags: python, networkx, gephi

The purpose of this code is to output node and edges file to be used in Gephi. I have used this code as base, which is for Chinese language and I am trying to re-create it to handle English language - https://pythonmana.com/2022/01/202201060336539842.html#%E5%9B%9B%E3%80%81%E5%AF%BC%E5%85%A5Gephi%20%E5%88%B6%E4%BD%9C%E7%BD%91%E7%BB%9C%E5%9B%BE

However, I am getting this error - "cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object"

Error is coming from this part of the code which is the main function, is there something wrong with it?

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
     os.chdir(r'path')
     filePath1 = r'.\node.xlsx'
     filePath2 = r'.\edge.xlsx'
     df = pd.read_excel(r'path')
     df2 = [w for w in df['Translated'] if len(w)>20]
     co_ist = [" ".join(my_cut(w)) for w in df2]
     node_str, edge_str = build_matrix(co_ist, is_reverse = True)
     str2csv(filePath1,node_str,'node')
     str2csv(filePath2,edge_str,'edge')
```

Error results from this particular line -

```
node_str, edge_str = build_matrix(co_ist, is_reverse = True)
```

Just adding the codes before the main function(given above) here for better clarity -

```py
def my_cut(text):
    word_dict_file = pd.read_excel(r'path')
    stop_words = []
    with open(r'path')
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            stop_words.append(line.strip())
        return [w for w in nltk.word_tokenize(text) if w not in stop_words and len(w)>1] #stop_words[:10]


def str2csv(filePath, s, x):
    if x=='node':
        with open(filePath, 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
            f.write("Label,Weight\r")
            f.write(s)
        print('Write file successful'+ filePath + 'View in')
    else:
        with open(filePath, 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as f: 
            f.write("Source,Target,Weight\r")
            f.write(s)
        print('Write file successful'+ filePath + 'View in')

#Build dictionary
def sortDictValue(dict, is_reverse): 
    tups = sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=is_reverse)
    s = ''
    for tup in tups: # Merge into csv Comma delimited format required
        s = s + tup[0] + ',' + str(tup[1]) + '\n'
    return s

#construct co-occurence matrix 
def build_matrix(co_authors_list, is_reverse): 
    node_dict = {} 
    edge_dict = {}
    row_authors_list = []
    connect_list = []
    global row_authors
    for row_authors in co_authors_list:
        row_authors_list = row_authors.split(' ')
    for index, pre_au in enumerate(row_authors_list):
        if pre_au not in node_dict:
            node_dict[pre_au] = 1
        else:
            node_dict[pre_au] += 1
        if pre_au == row_authors_list[-1]:
            break
        connect_list = row_authors_list[index+1:]
    for next_au in connect_list:
        A, B = pre_au, next_au
        if A==B:
            continue
        if A > B:
            A, B = B, A
            key = A+','+B
        if key not in edge_dict:
            edge_dict[key] = 1
        else:
            edge_dict[key] += 1
            node_str = sortDictValue(node_dict, is_reverse)
            edge_str = sortDictValue(edge_dict, is_reverse)
        return node_str, edge_str
```

Comment: Are you trying to build a *term co-occurence* network? If yes then Clement Levallois has built some online functions that can help you do it. Here is a [link](https://nocodefunctions.com/cowo/semantic_networks_tool.html) to the site.

Comment: @YannisP. Hi, yes I am trying to build a network chart.. I am aware of this website, but I wanted to try doing it using python itself. I am trying to get a running code which will at least output nodes and edges list(unsupervised) for me. So far no success

Comment: In that case the error basically tells you that the method build_matrix does not return two values, in some instance that causes the problem. Your code has “return” inside the for loop but can’t really see more. Reading from the main function is not exactly clear either.